# how to open email in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

hi i'm looking to send details of form in email after validation but i don't know how i put an alert in where i would like to send the details heres a sample of my code

```
if(compName)
{
    document.getElementById('country').focus();
    compName=true;
    if(compContry)
    {
        document.getElementById('Phone').focus();
        compContry=true;
        if(compphone)
        {
            document.getElementById('email').focus();
            compphone=true;
            if(compemail)
            {

                    //this is where i want to send details of form in email 
                    alert("Your Details Are Sent ");
                    compemail=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById('email').focus();
                    compemail=false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('Phone').focus();
                compphone=false;
            }


    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('country').focus();
        compContry=false;
    }
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('username').focus();
    compName=false;
}
```

}

Comment: Question isn't so clear.

Comment: Do you mean you want to send an email using JS?

Answer (score 6):

You can't send an email with javascript, the closest you can get would be a `mailto` which opens the default email client - but that won't send anything.

Email should be sent from the server - submit the form in the normal way, and construct the email on the server and send it. How you do this depends on what you are running on the server.

Answer (score 0):

you can use location.href to that:

```
var myMailAdressStr = "mailto:xxx@myyyy.zz?subject:Formvalidationbody&body="; + document.getElementById('username').value;
```

Note: This way opens you default email client and the browser does fill the defined fields. Javascript is unable to send an email in generally. Only serverside languages have got some ways to get an access to an email server and send a mail in real.

Comment: document.getElementById('username').value; do i repeat this part for each field as in Name ,country ,subject etc ? thanks for the help

Comment: @martin Yes, you have to do that. Note: the chars '\t' genearates a tab sign, '\n' generates a new line.

Comment: can i add them all in like ('username','country','subject','etc')

Comment: @martin: yes. you have to just append it to the parameter 'body' That's all. But pay attention on string length. The maximum limit of characters is 1024 letters. This limit comes from the HTML specification. The 1025th and so far will be truncated without any comment.