# E-mail a value which is returned by a function

Tags: javascript, email

I was wondering if it is possible to email a value which is returned by a function in javascript? or do i have to use php/ajax?

From the following example, I want to email abc to myself? How can it be done?

```
<html>
<head><script>
var t = "abc";
function test(){
return t;}
</script></head>
<body onload = "test()">
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to post it to your server via XHR, then your server can email it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct method. I would use jQuery' [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to post the relevant information to a PHP page which would then mail it using, at it's simplest, the aptly-named [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

In one of the script tags of the main page or in a separate .js file:

```
$.post("mailer.php", {data: "abc"}, function(data) {
  // Alert yourself whether it was successful if you want
});
```

And mailer.php (replace these with your own values):

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = $_POST['data'];
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: for posting do u mean something like this placed inside the function: ????
$.post('ajax/test.html', function(text) {
  $('.result').html(text);
});

Comment: Yes, although keep in mind here that you want to post **data**. So it would be more like `$.post("somefile.php", {data: "stuff"}, function(text) { ... })`. Note the second argument. Your example would successfully retrieve the output from test.html, but it wouldn't actually _send_ any. I edited a fuller example into my original post.

Comment: for example : if a variable called imageUrl consists of the url of the webpage screenshot, will the following example work ? $.post("mailer.php",{data:imageUrl},function(data)){...});

Comment: It should. The [$_POST variable in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) is just an array of strings (with special characters escaped). Anything that has a string equivalent -- strings, numbers and variables representing them -- can be passed without a problem.

Comment: but even then i need to set up a server rite inorder to send email using php?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very good explanation from another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801152/how-to-open-email-in-javascript):

> **You can't send an email with javascript**,
>    the closest you can get
>   would be a mailto which opens the
>   default email client - but that won't
>   send anything.
>
> Email should be sent from the server -
>   submit the form in the normal way, and
>   construct the email on the server and
>   send it....

Another answer there gives some details about using `mailto`.